# Distance to specific node incremental addition

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Let us say I have an empty graph `G` and a list of nodes `N` to add to the graph one-by-one. Let us say that I will have a node `X` that I do not yet know, but will know after I construct my graph `G`. My ultimate goal is to find the shortest distance from each node `N` to `X`, in the weighted graph `G` (For some context on why I need this, my graph `G` is fixed, while the node `X` can keep changing for each new problem.)

Each time I add a node from `N`, I also add the edges that connect the node to other relevant nodes

What is the most efficient way to do this? I have a few observations/notes.

1. Can I leverage the fact that the graph is constructed incrementally and nodes are added one-by-one. Can I compute some distance as nodes are being inserted.
2. Along similar lines, (and ignoring the incremental aspect), does it make sense to compute some notion of shortest distance between the nodes, `N` in the graph `G` such that when my node `X` finally comes in, it is easy to compute the distance to `X` from each node?
3. I'm using `networkx` in python, and the most naive approach I can think of is to construct the graph, insert `X` and then finally run `bellman_ford` or something similar. Which algorithm suits this purpose best, I would think `single_source_bellman_ford`, but I also see `single_source_dijkstra_path`. Which one is more ideal.

Thanks

Comment: I think some details must be missing.  If you only add nodes and not edges, the graph is trivial.  I don't know what it means to "know" a node vs "not know" a node.  Normally when we add a node to a graph, it is created as an isolated node with no edges; if you want to have edges, you need to separately add them as well.  So it seems like some details are missing from the problem statement.

Comment: Apologies for this. By adding a node, I always add appropriate edges that connect this node to other nodes that are relevant. Edited the question

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  From the first three sentences, it sounds like `X` is fixed and the graph is changing (by adding one node each time).  But then the parenthetical "For some context" says `G` is fixed and `X` is changing.  I don't understand how to reconcile those two.  They sound like they contradict each other.  I assume I am misunderstanding something.  Can you specify the algorithm by listing the inputs to the algorithm, and the desired output?

Comment: We're not a coding site, so questions about how to implement something are off-topic here, but we can suggest an algorithm.

Comment: I dont think I've specified that `X` is ever fixed. So, I construct the graph once, and later use the same graph `G` for multiple different `X`'s, each `x` from `X` is independent. So yes the graph `G` is fixed after construction. I'm looking for an algorithm, or even a high level approach to the problem, I can take care of the implementation

Comment: Is the input to the algorithm a graph $G$ and $X_1,\dots,X_k$?  And the desired output is the set $d_{i,v}$ for each $i=1,\dots,k$ and each vertex $v$, where $d_{i,v}$ is the distance from $X_i$ to $v$?  What does this have to do with adding a node to the graph one-by-one, since it is the same graph $G$ throughout?  I'm confused.